# Rails 500 Error - Strong Parmeters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

When attempting to **update** a model, I'm running into strong parameter errors. Create action works, update fails.

```
Started PATCH "/companies/6/users/10" for 71....... at 2017-02-21 06:27:27 +0000
Processing by UsersController#update as JS

Parameters: {"company_id"=>"6", "id"=>"10"}

User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]

SQL (3.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_activity_at" = '2017-02-21 06:27:27.940545' WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 9]]

User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

This error is not extremely helpful, least not to me :(

```
Completed 400 Bad Request in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:60:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `block in update'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:42:in `update'
```

Controller Params

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :role, :email, :company_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
```

Comment: I am using a link_to to patch this record.
Not sure how to structure the following to wrap everything with the :user param.


<%= link_to company_user_path(:company_id => current_user.company_id, :id => user), :method => :patch, remote: true do %> <%= render partial: "permission", locals: { role: user.role.to_s.upcase } %> <% end %>

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are receiving params in format of

```
{"company_id"=>"6", "id"=>"10"}
```

But according to your `user_params` method, You need it in format of:

```
{'user' => {"company_id"=>"6", "id"=>"10"}}
```

so that `params.require(:user)` will filter out the `user` params.
I guess, the problem is with the form.

Comment: Based on the comments here, I was able to make it work. It certainly doesn't look ruby-esque. If there a better or simpler way to write this?

`<%= link_to company_user_path("user[company_id]" => current_user.company_id, id: user), method: :patch, remote: true do %>
     <%= render partial: "permission", locals: { role: user.role.to_s.upcase } %>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

You either need to change your HTML to get the params in the following format.

```
{"user" => { "company_id"=>"6", "id"=>"10" } }
```

Using [from helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) will do that for you.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

or you need to change the user_params to

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:name, :role, :email, :company_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
```

**Note:** name of your input fields must be something like `"user[company_id]"` if you want to use `params.require(:user).permit(:company_id)`

Comment: Thanks, that certainly narrows it down. How do I structure the params in the format you outlined above in a link_to tag?



`<%= link_to company_user_path(:company_id => current_user.company_id, :id => user), :method => :patch, remote: true do %>
        <%= render partial: "permission", locals: { role: user.role.to_s.upcase } %>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

The code below means that your form parameters (once deserialized) must be encapsulated in a `user` param.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :role, :email, :company_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
```

Specifically, `require(:user)` means that the `user` key must be present at the root level, otherwise that error will be thrown.

```
permit(:name, :role, :email, :company_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
```

Returns a hash containing the keys provided in the arguments.

So providing data `{user: {company_id: '6', id: '10'}}` would solve this error.

If you're using a form to generate these results the input fields should be named in the form `modelName[attributeName]`, so `user[company_id]`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments here, I was able to make it work. It certainly doesn't look ruby-esque. Is there a better or simpler way to rewrite this?

```
<%= link_to company_user_path("user[company_id]" => current_user.company_id, id: user), method: :patch, remote: true do %>
   <%= render partial: "permission", locals: { role: user.role.to_s.upcase } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `<%= link_to company_user_path({'user' => { company_id: current_user.company_id, id: user }}), method: :patch, remote: true do %>`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others you need to have the parameters wrapped under a top-level key `user`. The easiest way to achieve this – without having to change your HTML – is to use [`ActionController::ParamsWrapper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html). Simply activate it in your `UsersController` like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters :user, format: [:json, :xml, :url_encoded_form, :multipart_form]
  …
end
```

You might narrow down the list of formats to the ones you’re actually using. Also, assuming you have an `User` model, you can omit the model name, too. Thus the line could become as simple as `wrap_parameters format: [:url_encoded_form]`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your form . You are not binding the `company_id` in the `user` model. 
Your param  should be like `{'user' => {'company_id' => 6, 'id' => 10}}` and so on...
So, bind the values in the user & then resend your ajax.